# How did East Asia circa 1500 produce cosmetics?

Tags: medieval-china

For a work of fiction, I need to know how one would produce cosmetics from the available products at those times (circa 1500).

I imagine I would need 
- beeswax, which was probably widely available
- oil - but which one? Linseed? Hemp seed? Perilla?
- butter - for concealers, butter-like products. Cocoa, Shea butter I think we're not really available. Would avocado work?
- pigments. I know white lead was common, probably some earth pigments as well.

Does anyone have any information about the ingredients available and used in those times?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: Are you asking about Japan, China or Korea?  Was there any butter in any of those regions at that time? I doubt that avocado was available.

Comment: We need more specifics: which 'cosmetics'? Make-up, wellness, ointments? For eyes, around the eyes, lips, general skin, teeth, hair; opticlly decorative, for smells/aroma; cleaning, protection… otherwise the approach chosen in the existing answer will fit nicely: once invented never (completely) out of style. Should this be about known, possible, actually in fashion, avantgarde trend or old style custom, hi/lo class…?

Comment: Of the pigments, the following were known in antiquity in Eurasia. White lead as you've mentioned; cinnabar was used as a red pigment in China from antiquity;  antimony sulfide or manganese oxide as black pigment for eyeshadow, also atramentum (lamp black) for this purpose. Also arsenic-based pigments: realgar and orpiment. ...I think you need a disclaimer on the copyright page of your book saying that most of these are poisonous!

Comment: @jlovegren Hard to believe people thought smearing neurotoxins on their faces was a good idea.  We've come a long way I guess.

Comment: This question could be better. The title asked "how" (i.e. process) but then the body focuses on "what" (i.e. the ingredients) with no reference to "how" of late medieval cosmetics. Nothing wrong per se, but it could be better.

Comment: @Ryan_L perceptive ancients recognized that workers at lead and mercury smelters were poisoned by the fumes, and they recognized that mercury should be transformed into cinnabar, but didn't jump to the conclusion that the poisonous essence of the metal was retained. I.e., cinnabar and mercury were assumed to be completely different substances which could be transformed the one into the other.

Comment: @Ryan_L but it is organic! ;)

Comment: Most of these ingredients were neither available at the time nor considered cosmetics. Very anachronistic guesses.

Answer (score 10):

Many of the following are anachonistic; I wanted to test to see if there was information on Asian cosmetics in history. I think the answer is yes; I selected the following from pages of results.

> 3000 BCE:
> The Chinese stain their fingernails with gum arabic, gelatin, beeswax, and egg. The colors are used as a representation of social class: Chou dynasty royals wear gold and silver, with subsequent royals wearing black or red. Lower classes are forbidden to wear bright colors on their nails.
>
> 1500 BCE:
> Chinese and Japanese citizens commonly use rice powder to make their faces white. Eyebrows are shaved off, teeth are painted gold or black, and henna dyes are applied to stain hair and faces.

[Cosmetics Info](https://cosmeticsinfo.org/Ancient-history-cosmetics)

Please also consult:

- [Wikipedia: China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_cosmetics#China)
- [WIkipedia: Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_cosmetics#Japan)
- [*GlamorFlare: History of Korean Cosmetics*](https://glamourflare.com/blogs/reviews/the-history-of-korean-cosmetics)

Comment: I'd just like to mention that while this is clearly relevant, it probably does not fit the time frame given in the OP. (I assume the OP meant 1500 CE, not 1500 BCE.)

Comment: For base oil, I have just generally *assumed* it would be refined animal-fat during medieval times, or even prior.  Unfortunately, I do not have references on this. Some parts of SEA still do this (home-made cosmetics), in the less developed regions. Again, no references off the top of my head.

Comment: @0range: Then again, not *that* much evolution of techniques occurred until the late medieval era.